# Win: How to add registry shell extension for all selected folders

Tags: windows, context-menu, shell-extensions

I would like to be able to add `Open Selected with Sublime Text 2` context menu that will open all selected items in one sublime text window (on the side bar). When I execute `"C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 2\sublime_text.exe" folder1 folder2` I indeed see a new sublime text window with `folder1` and `folder2` on the side bar. How do I add the context menu item? I added

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Open Folder with &Sublime Text 2\command 
"C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 2\sublime_text.exe" "%1"
```

This added a context menu item but it is good only for one folder - when I selected 2 folders and selected the `Open Folder with Sublime Text 2` it opened two windows of sublime text each for each folder.

I also tried to replace the `%1` with `%1 %2`, `%*` and `%V` but had no luck. Can someone help ? Is it even possible?

Comment: Do you have any programs that do this? (Usually easier to follow an existing example.)

Comment: @Richard - For example, when selecting multiple items I can use the context menu of 7zip to add them to an archive, Or if I select two folders I can use Beyond Compare's `compare` option to compare them.